# How to Properly Use Realtime Priority

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, real-time

My question may not really be about realtime processing, but then again, it may be.

My application has several threads that are far more important than the GUI, BUT, I do want the GUI to at least be usable. I don't want it locked at all times, and I do want to update the screen given results of processing I am performing.

Currently all my essential items are isolated in separate threads, and I call a delegate to my GUI to display results.

My GUI works, but if I change tabs, or minimize/maximize it, it has been known to hinder my other threads to the point where they can not perform their operations within the 0.1s time limit they are held to.

This is what I am doing to call my delegate:

```
delegate void FuncDelegate(ResultContainer Result);
FuncDelegate DelegatedDisplay= new FuncDelegate(DisplayResults);
//then later on
Invoke(DelegatedDisplay, Result);
```

Most of my critical processes are threads that run in continuous loops, pulling from and pushing to various buffers (ArrayLists and normal Lists).

One of my critical threads is launched every time, using:

```
Thread mythread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessResults));
mythread.Start();
```

The reason I thought to do this, instead of just having a thread running in a loop, pulling from lists, is that I thought perhaps the reason I was running out of clock time was that I have a polling loop that I worry consumes too many resources (although I am using Thread.Sleep(5) every time the poll turns up negative).

Does launching a new thread each time I need the concurrent process cost me valuable time? Should this be a loop? Are my loops to blame?

Can I give a thread higher priority than others, or is the use of Thread.Sleep my only option? If I do assign higher thread priorities, how can I be sure other threads can even survive?

Why are simple forms events hampering my other threads so much? Is there a way to give my GUI thread an assigned, lower amount of resources? Can I use a Thread.Sleep somehow to block Form events if the other threads are running out of clock time?

Short of an answer to all my frustrating questions, is there some kind of thread profiler I can be using to help figure my mess out? I tried using "Managed Stack Explorer" but somehow that doesn't always show what threads my application has.

Any help on this matter would help me greatly.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I think I have encountered something similar, with opening-closing-drawing windows (even by OTHER processes) somehow stalling a Realtime Priority thread.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev No, this isn't really "solved". I am using "BeginInvoke" and the "thread pool". Neither made significant improvements. What did help was putting a sleep in parts of the critical threads directly after critical events were handled. What that did was free up cycle time for the less critical threads to actually process. I found that if a less critical thread has to wait too long it ends up impacting the higher priority threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here's a start:

```
Invoke(DelegatedDisplay, Result);
```

This means that you are causing the background thread to wait until the UI thread *actually performs* the drawing operation, then proceed.  From the thread's point of view that's an eternity.  You might want to investigate asynchronous updates to the UI:

```
BeginInvoke(DelegatedDisplay, Result);
```

That's equivalent to telling the UI thread "when you have a chance, perform this drawing action", then proceeding with the work that you were doing.

You should be aware that this may cause thread-safety issues that didn't occur using `Invoke`, though.  For example, if the background thread is still modifying `Result` while the UI is attempting to draw, you might have unexpected race conditions.

See [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) vs [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx)

Comment: "MyThread" shown in my question is what currently does the invoke, and what it does is remove a result from a list, then communicate, then do the invoke using that Result. Do I need to protect "Result" in this case? Result is my own class, so can I declare a new result as a copy, then pass that in my BeginInvoke? I still struggle with knowing when a pointer is being thrown around, and when I'm making new data.

Comment: If you are not modifying `Result` or any of it's contents on "MyThread" after calling `BeginInvoke`, you should be OK.

Comment: This may be another silly thing to ask, but if I call a function multiple times that declares and launches a thread, no matter how many times that function is called, the threads *are* separate threads, even if I call the function twice before the thread completes once.

Comment: That's correct, assuming that you are doing it as you describe in your question.  You should be aware that it is generally more performant to use the thread pool than creating new threads for low-latency work.  Creating a thread takes a ***long*** time.  To paraphrase Eric Lippert, "assume that starting a thread takes about 100 years, because to the processor thats about how long it takes".

Comment: Is a threadpool good to use in the case? You've convinced me that making a new thread each time is inefficient. Is use of the thread pool timely? Do I have to worry about running out of threads somehow, and not having one available to me when I need it and cannot afford to wait?

Comment: The thread pool on .NET 4 has a default of 250 worker threads per CPU.  If you are hitting that limit you have bigger problems- you'll be spending so much time context switching that you will never get any work done anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm making this correct. I still have my problem but I noticed a marginal improvement in my application after switching to the thread pool instead of just making a new thread.

Comment: Did you try begin invoke instead of invoke?

Comment: Yes, and not to worry. It didn't solve my problem, but I can see that this is a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Using marshaling techniques like `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` to update the UI is part of the problem. In fact, I rarely use marshaling operations for the UI and worker thread interactions because it is not that great of a solution. Well, to be frank, it can be (and usually is) the worst solution in most cases of this nature.

What I typically do is have the worker thread publish its results or progress to a shared data structure and have the UI thread poll for it using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (or `DispatcherTimer`) on an interval that is tuned to work best for the situation at hand.

Here is what it might look like.

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
  private ConcurrentQueue<ResultContainer> results = new ConcurrentQueue<ResultContainer>();

  public UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    // Limit the number of results to be processed on each cycle so that
    // UI does not stall for too long.
    int maximumResultsToProcessInThisBatch = 100;

    ResultContainer result;
    for (int i = 0; i < maximumResultsToProcessInThisBatch; i++)
    {
      if (!results.TryDequeue(out result)) break;
      UpdateUiControlsHere(result);
    }
  }

  private void WorkerThread()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      // Do work here.
      var result = new ResultContainer();
      result.Item1 = /* whatever */;
      result.Item2 = /* whatever */;
      // Now publish the result.
      results.Enqueue(result);
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, people have been so programmed to automatically use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to update the UI that they ignore better solutions. It has gotten to the point where these marshaling techniques fit into the realm of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). I probably sound like a broken record regarding this topic because I rip on it all of the time. The technique I used above has the following advantages.

- It breaks the tight coupling between the UI and worker threads that the marshaling operations impose.
- The worker thread does not have to wait for a response from the UI thread as would be the case with `Invoke`.
- There is no chance of saturating the UI message queue as would be the case with `BeginInvoke`.
- You get more throughput on both the UI and worker threads.
- The UI thread gets to dictate when and how often the UI thread should be updated.
- You do not have to litter your code (and I mean that quite literally) with `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` calls.
- Marshaling operations are expensive.
- The code ends up looking more elegant.

> Does launching a new thread each time I need the concurrent process
>   cost me valuable time? Should this be a loop? Are my loops to blame?

I would avoid creating threads willy-nilly. If you can keep the thread running in a loop that would be better.

> Can I give a thread higher priority than others, or is the use of
>   Thread.Sleep my only option? If I do assign higher thread priorities,
>   how can I be sure other threads can even survive?

Giving your worker thread a higher priority would probably help in this case. `Thread.Sleep(5)` will not sleep for 5ms though. It just does not work that way. By the way there are some special values that you can pass to `Thread.Sleep`.

- Thread.Sleep(0) yields to any thread with the same or higher priority on any processor.
- Thread.Sleep(1) yields to any thread on any processor.

> Why are simple forms events hampering my other threads so much? Is
>   there a way to give my GUI thread an assigned, lower amount of
>   resources? Can I use a Thread.Sleep somehow to block Form events if
>   the other threads are running out of clock time?

It is because you are using `Invoke`. Avoiding the marshaling operations will help significantly since it decouples the threads. Do not use `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread. The UI thread *must* remain unblocked for it to work properly. If you use the solution I propose above then it is much easier to throttle the UI thread.

Comment: Wow, well I'm doing one thing right by not using Thread.Sleep on the main thread. I suppose I've always believed that running a loop that essentially polls a list was always less efficient than launching an action for the update at the moment I require it to. Can anyone else comment on which solution is better? If my GUI updates are non-critical, is BeginInvoke ok to use? Or does use of the BeginInvoke cause inefficiency everywhere, even on my critical threads?

Comment: Well after a pile of trial and error, I found that my app is still being mangled by the GUI, even after removing all instances BeginInvoke and Invoke. Additionally I removed the timer, and did no GUI updating at all, and I'm still going over time. There must be something else going on that is blocking my vital threads.