# How Can I Make Designer-Made Form Events Yield to Other Threads?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

How do I make GUI events yield to a given thread? By GUI events I mean things like opening a sub-form, selecting different tabs, or minimizing/maximizing my form or changing focus.

When my working thread gets data, can I throttle resources over to it, and deny those resources from other processes or threads in my application?

***History:***
In my question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834329/how-to-properly-use-realtime-priority) I explain a scenario where I am concerned with my Invoke to my main form causing hang-ups on my critical threads. It was then revealed to me that I have the option to "BeginInvoke".

Now I find that while BeginInvoke gets me half-way there, I'm still unable to avoid hang-ups in my critical threads. When I say "critical threads" I am refering to a thread that takes approximately 60ms to cycle, but must finish cycling before 130ms has elapsed. It sits there looping, polling a data list. When the data shows up, it generally takes between 40 and 60ms to finish processing.

I **had** (and technically, I plan to reinstate) a second thread throwing BeginInvokes at my form to update the user on the status of the run. I currently, for debugging purposes, am not doing that.

I did some profiling, and I noticed that I almost always keep my process time down far below 100ms, which I need to be, because my application needs to output results no later than when the next package of data appears (every 100ms, but for this example I slowed that to 130ms). When I interact with my form, by say changing focus, or minimizing/maximizing it, I can see my process time spike above 1s. I assume this is because silly things like minimizing or maximizing, or other re-draw events, are plundering all my precious clock time.

***Platform:***
I am using Visual C# 2008 with WinForms. The target machine runs Windows XP. I have attempted closing Windows Explorer, and running my application on Normal, High, and Realtime, priority, but I still see a nearly identical impact when manipulating my form.

***Edit***
I have tried to use Thread.CurrentThread.Priority to throttle my priority at critical times during my worker loop. This somehow isn't able to take those resources away from my GUI and operations that involve redrawing the GUI still rule over my poor worker thread.

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are still having, obviously using Invoke() was wrong.  You are still booting XP, how old is that machine?  Does it have only one cpu core?  Get the hardware you need.

Comment: Well, the Invoke is gone now. If you can imagine, I have a form that is currently doing nothing, and the worker thread I described. Moving that form around, minimizing it and maximizing it for example, or telling it to open some child dialogue seems to make my worker thread take 10 to 20x as long as typical to complete. The target hardware is an intel Core 2 Duo at 2.4Ghz. I realize it's not the newest thing, but it's certainly not just chugging along. My target platform is XP due to some industrial requirement.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, that should never happen on a multicore cpu.  One core is doing the expensive UI updates, the other one is free to keep itself occupied with the data processing and nothing else.  Maybe you've got some kernel driver thread doing major work to supply the data, it is entirely unguessable.  Get yourself a profiler.

Comment: Any recommendations? Should I be trying to force certain threads to certain CPUs? I thought that was always best left to the OS.

Comment: .NET already uses several threads, The UI Thread, the Rendering Thread, 2 threads for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try and set the Thread Priority of your worker class to RealTime using the [Thread.Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) property?

Based on the description of [Scheduling Priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this should give a higher priority to your worker thread. However, this will cause your GUI to stutter along, so you probably only want to set the priority high during critical time periods.

Comment: Yes I have tried this, and while it does make the GUI mildly "stutter-y" it doesn't seem to impact my other threads positively. It seems that when moving around forms within my application it doesn't matter what I try to do to thread priority, that seems to take residence. I'll edit that in to my question, sorry.

Comment: I think you should do some thread level profiling to see what exactly is happening. Windows is not a "real-time" OS, which means it doesn't guarantee a certain % of CPU to any thread/process, it does it's best given what the user is doing (which can be any crazy thing). However, given enough CPU power you should be able to prioritize things. One other tip is to try and distribute your processing across more threads. The more threads you have working the higher the % time you'll get.

Comment: Be careful when adding threads. Consider the cost of context switching vs. the thread's work load. Consider that your hardware is under-powered relative to the application's processing requirements.

Comment: Be careful when adding threads. Consider the cost of context switching vs. the thread's work load. Consider that your hardware is under-powered relative to the application's processing requirements. Which processor(# Cores, # Threads, L2 Cache)? What memory organization(# channels)? Dedicated/Shared graphics memory? Intel Core 2 Duo(2 Cores, 2 Threads) E4300: 1.8GHz(L2=2MB) E8600: 3.33GHz (L2=6MB)